# Conversão de data no SQL server após usar na clausula where?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-select

Preciso extrair vendas de um período de data tal até data tal. Por exemplo, entre `01/04/2011` e `30/04/2011`.

Não estou conseguindo trazer o resultado do período em questão. No caso, estou usando a tabela *AdventuresWorks2019* da Microsoft para praticar.

Só consigo chegar até aqui:

```
select pp.productID, 
       pp.Name as "Descrição do produto", 
       pp.ProductNumber as "Número do Produto", 
       po.Unitprice as "Preço Unitário",
       po.LineTotal as "valor total", 
       po.Orderqty as "Quantidade do Produto", 
       po.duedate as "Data do Pedido"
    from production.product pp 
    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail po 
    on pp.ProductID = po.ProductID
    where DueDate ( Daqui não consigo passar)
```

Preciso exatamente o período entre determinadas datas.

Além disso, o campo está no formato `datetime`, ou seja, a data aparece como `2011-04-30 00:00:00:000`, mas eu quero exibir como `30/04/2011`.

Comment: A data "30/04/2011" deve participar do resultado? É o mês completo ou realmente entre datas? É que tem a questão de ser entre datas inclusive ou a possibilidade de excluir as datas inicial e final.

Comment: Bom dia.Então, preciso data completa , somente o dia mes e ano, mas se eu tenho que converter antes ?ou seja  tenho que usar no select ? ou tenho que usar no whwere? pois ainda não tive o resultado esperado , eu porque dentro da data especificada ainda tem informação e não está buscando

Comment: No seu exemplo, vc usa a data inicial e a data final que representa um mês completo. Você sempre estará interessado em um mês completo? ex: 05/2020, 06/2020.  Ou você pode ter períodos entre datas, ex: 15/05/2020 a 15/06/2020  ?

Comment: como o campo esta em formato datetime 2011-04-30 00:00:00:000 eu quero fazer que mostre apenas a data que selelecionei entre 01/04/2011 até 30/04/2011 , mas onde eu usar a conversão ?  eu uso no Where ou no select? Por favor preciso destas dicas, pois na funções de data e string ainda sou noob. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para formatação da data, usei `convert(varchar(10),po.DueDate ,103)`, e para o `where` utilizei `where po.DueDate between '01/04/2011' and '30/04/2011'`.

A query ficou assim:

```
select
  pp.productID,
  pp.Name as "Descrição do produto",
  pp.ProductNumber as "Número do Produto",
  po.Unitprice as "Preço Unitário",
  po.LineTotal as "valor total",
  po.Orderqty as "Quantidade de Produto",
  convert(varchar(10),po.DueDate ,103) as "Data de Pedido"
from production.product pp 
  inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail po 
  on pp.ProductID = po.ProductID
where po.DueDate   between  '01/04/2011' and '30/04/2011'
  order by po.DueDate
```

Fiz a conversão direta da coluna que estava no formato `datetime` e o resultado foi o esperado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você vai filtrar pelo campo duedate da tabela PurchaseOrderDetail, e este campo for datetime, você pode filtrar por intervalo de datas utilizando BETWEEN. O filtro pelo intervalo de datas que você informou ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
select pp.productID, 
       pp.Name as "Descrição do produto", 
       pp.ProductNumber as "Número do Produto", 
       po.Unitprice as "Preço Unitário",
       po.LineTotal as "valor total", 
       po.Orderqty as "Quantidade do Produto", 
       po.duedate as "Data do Pedido"
    from production.product pp 
    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail po 
    on pp.ProductID = po.ProductID
    where po.duedate BETWEEN '2011-04-01 00:00:00' and '2011-04-30 23:59:59'
```

Comment: então, se eu fizer desta forma da erro de formatação mas se eu for usar a data sem a barra , '20110401 ' and '20110430' ele traz com a data e hora, mas ainda dentro da data ainda não buscando, pois o formato da data não é interessante, quero apresentar desta forma 01/04/2011.